# No XML documentation / IntelliSense for WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022, xml-documentation

I'm using `Visual Studio 17.5.4` and `.NET SDK 7.0.5`

Upon creating a new WPF application, I have no XML documentation available in IntelliSense for the WPF library.

Browsing to source (F12) shows the library at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\7.0.5\`

This is in contrast to a WinForms app, which has the docs in IntelliSense, with F12 showing sources via SourceLink.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: Added screenshots as requested. Note how there is no documentation for the WPF framework classes.

[image: Hovering over a WPF class (System.Windows.Window)]

[image: Go to definition (F12)]

Comment: If possible, could you please clarify about this issue? What do you mean "the docs in IntelliSense"? Could you please provide some screenshots about your issue? :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I have added screenshots as requested. Note how there is no documentation for the WPF framework classes.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the source code after you press ctrl+"left click" is the documention you want? :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Yes, or when simply hovering over the class name for IntelliSense docs. The issue would seem to be that the XML docs are missing for the WPF library.

Comment: You mean press ctrl+"left click" can't go to the source code? I tested on my side and it seems work.

Comment: Hi, it seems I meet the similar situation on my side. Please try right click the class and then click 'go to implementation', after that, you should be able to go to the source code and be able to use ctrl+"left click". :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT The issue is not Ctrl-Click. It's that the documentation for the WPF library is missing. You can see this in the screenshots I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/pull/7906) has been identified and fixed in the upcoming release of dotnet (expected version - 7.0.9).

The reason for failure was the incorrect mapping version of the supporting libraries that were responsible for generating intellisense.